# Run time analysis of a program with nested for loops

Tags: algorithm-analysis, asymptotics, runtime-analysis, loops

### Problem

Let's say we are given a program and we want to find an **algorithm**  that analyses its *asymptotic complexity*. This program can only have two types of statements: `do_something` and the `for` loop. The `for` loop is defined as followed.

```
for <variable> = <from> .. <to>
    <body>
```

The `for` loop makes the `<variable>` iterate from `<from>` to `<to>` (except when `<from>` is greater than `<to>`, then `<body>` won't be executed at all)

`<body>` must be a statement again (so either `for` or `do_something`).

`<variable`> is a lowercase letter `a..z` except for `n`, which is defined prior to the program.

`<from>, <to>` can be any variables defined in the outer loop. Addtionally, `<from>` can have the value 1 and `<to>` can be `n`.

Example:

```
for i = 1 .. n
    for j = 1 .. i
        for k = j .. n
            do_something
```

Let $f(n)$ be the number of times `do_something` is executed as a function of $n$. We want to know the **asymptotic complexity** of $f(n)$. For a non-negative integer $k$ and a positive rational $C$, we say that $C \cdot n^k$ is the asymptotic complexity of $f(n)$ if:

$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{f(n)}{C \cdot n^k} = 1$

In the above's example, the asymptotic complexity would be $\frac{1}{3}n^3$.

### Solution (?)

I could not come up with an efficient ***algorithm*** to solve this problem so I looked it up (which was in a foreign language). However, I only understand a portion of it:

> Every `for` loop will give us inequalities: `for i = j .. k` means
>   that $j \leq i$ and $i \leq k$. First create a directed graph where
>   each variable corresponds to one node and for every inequality $i \leq j$
>   we create a directed edge from node $i$ to node $j$. If we consider
>   the strongly connected components (SCC) then we can notice that if two
>   variables $i, j$ are in the same SCC, they must be equal. Now let's
>   consider the condensed graph G' (meaning that we consider every SCC as
>   one node) and let the number of nodes be $m$. The time complexity
>   would be $C \cdot n^m$, where $C = \frac{\text{number of topological sorting in G'}}{m!}$

So I understand that $f(n)$ is a polynomial of degree $m$, but can not explain how the the coefficient of $n^m$ should have the $C$ as described above. Can anyone help me understand this solution?

Comment: As [our reference question explains](/questions/23593/is-there-a-system-behind-the-magic-of-algorithm-analysis), `for` loops are rather easy: translate them into (nested) sums, the simplify.

Comment: Are you after an algorithm? Not sure what the one you're citing is about. I'd go with computer algebra for simplifying sums.

Comment: Yes, I am about finding an algorithm that can parse a program (defined in such a simple language) and calculate it's asymptotic complexity.

Comment: Such an algorithm [does not exist](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/5004/are-runtime-bounds-in-p-decidable-answer-no), at least if you permit *all* programs. Restricted to only for-loops with "simple" boundaries might work, though.

Comment: Yes, I am aware of the link that you sent me, but I am asking for a specific set of programs (as described above). The solution that was provided to the given (really restricted) problem is essentially an $O(m 2^m)$ solution, where $m$ is the number of for loops (due to counting the number of topological orderings via Dynamic Programming), but that's enough for me. I just wanted to understand the correctness behind this solution.